# PrimeNG p-tree filter modal search bar customization

Tags: html, css, angular, tree, primeng

I have a p-tree with the default search bar and pi-search icon. I want to customize the search icon with X pi-times icon when some search value is entered in the search bar. Is it possible?

I have implemented separate primeNg icon beside the search bar but it is getting distorted when the screen resolution is changed.

```
<!-- Custom Filter Search close icon -->
  <div style="margin-top: 20px" class="matDividerDisplay">
    <div style="float: right; position: relative; margin-left: -131px">
      <p-button
        type="button"
        *ngIf="!showSearchIcon"
        class="iconColor"
        (click)="onSearchCancelClick()"
        icon="pi pi-times"
      ></p-button>

      <p-button
        type="button"
        *ngIf="showSearchIcon"
        class="iconColor"
        icon="pi pi-search"
      ></p-button>
    </div>
    <!-- Custom Filter Search close icon -->
```

I want ways to place this custom icon beside the search bar and it should stay on all screen resolutions. Any guidance on this?